# Get data from xml file

Tags: php, xml

I have a long xml file containing articles data , I want to extract some of them (pmid,doi,abstract)and I have a file containing the "PMID" or "Titles" of the articles I need to take , How could I do it?
This is the link to the xml file : https://github.com/r03ert0/brainspell/blob/master/data/brainspell-15July2014.xml.zip

Thanks in advance

Comment: please share some code on what you have tried and failed

Comment: This can come handy: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: I think using XMLReader is more appropriate here since the file is big (47Mb).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, no the file is like 8MB big. Simplexml may handle that filesize easily...

Comment: @MattBackslash: You have forgotten to unzip the archive.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte oh, you're right. Hahah :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use **PHP SimpleXML Parser**. Example:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("file");
```

Then you can use **$xml** to access different attributes:

```
echo $xml->pmid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not really the idea to find people for writing you some free code, but let me help you out...

First, learn working with the [simplexml](http://php.net/manual/de/function.simplexml-load-file.php) function.

Then you just have to loop through the object and you have the access to your needed fields:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('testfile.xml');
$pmid = $xml->paper[0]->pmid[0]
print_r($pmid);
```

Here, the PMID is already saved in a variable.

Kind regards